# Compute $\iiint_Vy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz$ where $V=\{(x, y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid 2x+4y-z\le 8,x,y\ge 0,z\le -4\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Compute $$\iiint_Vy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\,,$$ where $$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid 2x+4y-z\le 8,x,y\ge0,z\le-4\}$$

Here is what I did and I want to know if I am right.

Let $D=\{(x, z)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid2x-z\le8, x\ge 0, z\le -4\}$ (the projection of $V$ on the $xz$ plane). Then, $$V=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\mid (x, y)\in D, 0\le y\le \frac{1}{4}(8-2x+z)\}$$ and we have $$\iiint_Vy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz=\iint_D\left(\int_0^{\frac14(8-2x+z)}y\,\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dz,$$ which is an integral that I can compute, so I won't add the calculations here.

My question is whether my set $D$, the projection of $V$ on the $xz$ plane, is correct. As far as I know, everytime I want to write such a projection I just erase the component that is $0$ on that coordinate plane and the other variables satisfy the same constraints.

Comment: In your last equation change $d y \to d z$.

Comment: Also, in the definition of $D$ there is of course $(x,\color{red}z)$ the point. Then what is done is to write the boundary condition in the "right order", letting $y$ be constrained at last with interval extremities depending on $x,z$. It is important that this interval is not empty, and it is the only point to take care. Looks good as it is...

Comment: @jim thank you, I initially wanted to project $V$ on $xy$ and this is why I forgot to change some things

Comment: @dan_fulea thank you! So, whenever I want to do this trick, I just eliminate the coordinate I want to constrain in terms of the others and the other ranges stay that same, right?

Comment: Yes. We have here linear inequalities, so things are simple. (Sometimes we need to solve an algebraic equation of degree 2 or higher, or even a transcendental one, at any rate, the solution set is generally either empty, or a (degenerated) interval, or a union of such intervals.) Here, we just take $2x+4y-z\le 8$, $x,y\ge0$, $z\ge-4$, and write in the "other" order, mentioning $y$ last. So:  $x\ge 0$, $z\ge -4$, and for such a pair $(x,z)$ **there exists** a $y\ge 0$ with $2x-z\le 8-4y\le 8$. (Else the projection is empty.) The existence is cleared quickly, testing $y=0$ is enough.

Comment: But the region is not bound if $z \geq - 4$. There has to be an upper bound of $z$. But if $z \leq -4$, then yes you have region bound for $x, y \geq 0$.

Comment: Please check the equations you have typed in

Comment: @MathLover Yes, that's a typo, I will edit it right away, thank you!

Comment: Yes now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid 2x+4y-z\le 8,x,y\ge0,z\le-4\}$

Plane $2x + 4y - z = 8$ intersects z-axis ($x = y = 0$) at $z = - 8$. Also at $z = -4, 2x + 4y - z \leq 8 \implies x + 2y \leq 2$.

The integral can be set up in different orders but if go in the order $dz \ dx \ dy$, the region in plane $z = -4$ is given by $ \ x, y \geq 0, x+2y \leq 2$.

For lower bound of $z$, $ \ 2x + 4y - z \leq 8 \implies z \geq 2x + 4y - 8$

So bounds are $2x + 4y - 8 \leq z \leq - 4, 0 \leq x \leq 2 - 2y, 0 \leq y \leq 1$ and the integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{2-2y}\int_{2x+4y-8}^{-4} y \  dz \ dx \ dy$